# Ejercicio condicionales javaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio simple en javaScript pero por alguna razón no me sale correctamente.
Tengo que lanzar una ventana que le pida al usuario introducir el precio del viaje y en otra ventana que introduzca el dinero del que dispone. 
Si el dinero del que dispone es mayor o igual que el precio del viaje muestra "Sácate el billete" y actualiza el dinero disponible.

En caso negativo lanza un mensaje que traiga: "No dispones de suficiente dinero para viajar".

Por alguna razón siempre me entra por el else.
Espero vuestras respuestas,
gracias.

> Introduje 400 en "Introduzca precio de viaje" y 1000 en "Introduzca dinero disponible"

Ejercicio condicionales

## Viaje a Punta Cana

```
<script>
    var precioViaje= prompt("Introduzca el precio del viaje");
    var dineroDisponible= prompt("Introduzca el dinero disponible");



    if(dineroDisponible>=precioViaje){

        alert("Sácate el billete");
        dineroDisponible=dineroDisponible-precioViaje;
    }else{

        window.alert("No dispones de suficiente dinero para viajar");
    }

    window.alert("Te quedan "+ dineroDisponible +" euros.");


</script>
```

Comment: El problema tiene pinta de ser por la comparacion de tipos. lo que devuelve `promt` es `string` y para que haga comparaciones numericas han de ser `ints`. te sugiero que mires metodos como `number()` o `parseInt()` que pasen ese string a int. Un saludo!

Comment: @lois6b no parece que dé resultado. Probé con parseInt() y también con number(). Sigue dando problemas la aplicación.

Comment: @lois6b ya me funciona. Tuve que hacer un parseInt como me indican en la respuesta de abajo. El problema era que no estaba guardando el parseInt en una variable. Muchas gracias por vuestra atención y vuestras respuestas ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

convierte los prompt en int de esta manera

```
var precioViaje= prompt("Introduzca el precio del viaje");
var dineroDisponible= prompt("Introduzca el dinero disponible");
var num1 = parseInt(precioViaje);
var num2 = parseInt(dineroDisponible);

if(num2>=num1){

    alert("Sácate el billete");
    num2=num2-num1;
}else{

    window.alert("No dispones de suficiente dinero para viajar");
}

window.alert("Te quedan "+ num2 +" euros.");
```

La función parseInt te devuelve el primer numero de la cadena, si el primer número de una cadena no se puede convertir en int el valor que devuelve es NaN. En el caso de querer convertir por ejemplo "123.45" devolvería el primer número 132 y en el caso de "1234 prueba 34" el valor devuelto sería 1234.

Comment: Buena respuesta, lo unico que cambiaria seria el nombre de las variables `num1` y `num2`, ya que estos no son representativos.